# Как удалить список элементов в процедуре Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

При нажатии кнопки запускается функция. При первом запуске создается 5 текстовых полей, при следующем запуске эти поля должны быть удалены. В цикле создан список объектов.
В блоке else пытаюсь обратиться к списку list и вызвать метод destroy(). Возникает ошибка local variable 'list' referenced before assignment. То есть при повторном запуске программа не видит созданный ранее список.
p.s. Переменная iden индикатор повторного запуска программы

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Exchange_script")
root.geometry("910x650+50+50")

iden = 0
def click_gen():
    global iden
    if hi == 0:
        nfolders = 5
        nrow = 5
        m = 0
        k = 2
        list = ['s1'] 
        while nfolders > 0 :
            list.append('s' + str(k))
            list[m] = Entry(root, width="10", justify='center')
            list[m].grid(column=0, row=nrow)
            list[m].insert(0, "Name" + str(m+1))
            nfolders = nfolders - 1
            nrow = nrow + 1
            m = m + 1
            k = k + 1
    else:
        j = 5
        while j > 0:
            list[j-1].destroy() #здесь возникает ошибка
            j = j - 1
    hi = hi + 1

btndel = Button(text="run",
             background="#C0C0C0",
             foreground="black",
             width=12,
             height=1,
             font="Helvetica 8",
             command=click_gen
             )

btndel.grid(column=2, row=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Не надо называть переменные ключевыми словами `Python`, а то потом
  сюрпризы будут, так что `list` - это неудачное название для
  переменной, назовите хотя бы `lst`.
- Проще всего объявить вашу переменную со списком глобальной через `global`. Кстати, вы же уже объявляете переменную `iden` как
  `global`, но при этом никак её не используете.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Exchange_script")
root.geometry("910x650+50+50")

fields = list()

def click_gen():
    if fields:
        for f in fields:
            f.destroy()
        return

    for i in range(5):
        entry = Entry(root, width="10", justify="center")
        entry.grid(column=0, row=(i+5))
        entry.insert(0, "Name" + str(i + 1))
        fields.append(entry)

btndel = Button(text="run",
             background="#C0C0C0",
             foreground="black",
             width=12,
             height=1,
             font="Helvetica 8",
             command=click_gen
             )

btndel.grid(column=2, row=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском языке, постарайтесь оставлять более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно нажав кнопку править.